# ParseExact with format "dMMyyyy" not recognizing date

Tags: c#

I was looking in the Microsoft doc's and I can't find any explanation why `ParseExact` doesn't understand my date.

Could somebody explain why this code throws an exception?

```cs
DateTime.ParseExact("6092019", "dMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)
```

Comment: @Aybe `d` will match one or two digit values. [Example](https://rextester.com/LGIAAE29396).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs: [DateTime.ParseExact Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8#definition)

> If format is a custom format pattern that **does not include date or
>   time separators** (such as "yyyyMMddHHmm"), **use the invariant culture
>   for the provider parameter and the widest form of each custom format
>   specifier**. For example, if you want to specify hours in the format
>   pattern, specify the wider form, "HH", instead of the narrower form,
>   "H".

So in your case you probably should use approach suggested in John's answer - add "missing" zero and parse with wider date format "dd"

Answer (score 5):

The problem here seems to be that `d` can be a one-digit or two-digit date, so the parser struggles to determine if `"2102019"` refers to the 2nd of November 2019, or the 21st of... and then it breaks. With delimiters, the parser is able to act more intelligently. It will happily parse `"2-10-2019"` using `"d-MM-yyyy"`.

My suggested solution to your problem is to pad the string, and change your format string:

```
string dateToParse = "6092019";
string paddedDateToParse = dateToParse?.PadLeft(8, '0'); // 06092019
DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(paddedDateToParse, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/XVNYW84261)

Comment: There is no problem, becouse MMyyyy have constant length, and there is no place to wrong interpretation.

Comment: @Leszek Yes, I can see that. Now please can you demonstrate in the code for `ParseExact` where the length of the string is taken into consideration? You're thinking like a human, not like a computer.